# Oracle exception handling - finding which exception was thrown

Tags: oracle11g

I have a block of code like this:

```
DECLARE

....a couple custom exceptions....

BEGIN

....do stuff....

EXCEPTION
  WHEN exception1 OR exception2 THEN
    ....do a bunch of stuff that is common to both exceptions

END;
```

After all that code runs that is common to both exceptions, I want to branch and take different actions based on which exception was raised.  Is there a way to get the exception name so that I can add something like this?

```
IF exception1 THEN
  ...take action 1...
ELSE
  ...take action 2...
END IF;
```

I can't find anything in Oracle's docs, but it might be because I don't know how to word it properly.

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Comment: How are you declaring the exceptions?  Are you assigning them error numbers via `pragma exception_init` or just declaring a named exception?  Is there a reason that you wouldn't take the common bits, put that in a separate procedure, and just call that procedure from each exception handler?

Comment: They are just named exceptions; I'm not using the exception_init pragma.  Putting the common parts into a separate procedure would work, but this is a small procedure, and I didn't want to have to create another one just for the exception handling.  Figured Oracle would provide a way to do this.  I suppose I could use raise_application_error instead of named exceptions and simply have my exception handler capture WHEN OTHERS and check for the SQLCODE, but I was hoping to do this a bit more cleanly.

Comment: Thanks, guys, I suppose I'll have to take one of these routes.  It's strange that Oracle allows you to use the same handler for multiple exceptions, but no way to determine which specific exception was raised.  Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 1):

Well, my suggestion is pretty similar to Justin's, but I'll post it anyway for the sake of showing a slightly different approach.  This differs by saving the SQLCODE and SQLERRM (error message) into variables which are used later to format custom errors like Oracle errors:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2    my_exception_1 EXCEPTION;
  3    my_exception_2 EXCEPTION;
  4    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( my_exception_1, -20001 );
  5    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( my_exception_2, -20002 );
  6
  7    err_nbr    NUMBER;         -- Holds a SQL error number if an exception occurs.
  8    err_msg    VARCHAR2(1000); -- Holds a SQL error message if an exception occurs.
  9  BEGIN
 10    raise_application_error(-20002, 'Custom error -20002 was raised');
 11  EXCEPTION
 12    when my_exception_1 OR my_exception_2 then
 13      err_nbr := SQLCODE;
 14      err_msg := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 1000);
 15      dbms_output.put_line('error 1 or 2 occured');
 16
 17    CASE err_nbr
 18      WHEN -20001 then
 19        dbms_output.put_line('my_exception_1 message: ' || err_msg);
 20      WHEN -20002 then
 21        dbms_output.put_line('my_exception_2 message: ' || err_msg);
 22      ELSE  -- Always expect the unexpected!
 23        dbms_output.put_line('UNKNOWN ERROR: ' || err_msg);
 24    END CASE;
 25  END;
 26  /
error 1 or 2 occured
my_exception_2 message: ORA-20002: Custom error -20002 was raised

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of approaching the problem.  A couple that jump to mind for me

One is to factor out the common bits into a procedure either as its own stand-alone object, a private method within the package (since almost every procedure belongs in a package), or as a part of your procedure declaration.  For example

```
DECLARE
  l_ex1 exception;
  l_ex2 exception;

  procedure do_something_common
  as
  begin
    <<common code>>
  end do_something_common;
BEGIN
  <<do something>>
EXCEPTION
  WHEN l_ex1
  THEN 
    do_something_common;
    <<do something else>>
  WHEN l_ex2
  THEN
    do_something_common;
    <<do something else>>
END;
```

Another option would be to give the exceptions error codes and branch based on that

```
DECLARE
  l_ex1 exception;
  l_ex2 exception;

  pragma exception_init( l_ex1, -20001 );
  pragma exception_init( l_ex2, -20002 );
BEGIN
  <<do something>>
EXCEPTION
  WHEN l_ex1 or l_ex2
  THEN 
    do_something_common;

    if( sqlcode = -20001 )
    then
      <<something>>
    else
      <<something else>>
    end if;
END;
```